# date is not display in proper maner in exported csv file

Tags: php, csv

I am showing date like this format : `01/03/2017 12:11`

when I export my csv file first time then it is showing like below:

[image]

after that when I resize that column manually then it is show me like this

[image]

date is correct but it is showing me in on proper design(in one side shows me in zig zag )

can any one help me to resolve this ?

Comment: How do you generate the content for this column? Seems as though you're getting an issue with it because you're formatting as American, but using DD/MM/YYYY. American format is MM/DD/YYYY. Hence the "zig-zag". But I don't think CVS can resize the column, it has no formatting like that.

Answer (score 1):

In excel just change format by selection column and select proper format as you want.
Select Column ->More num format -> Date-> Format you like

at database side date will remain same

Comment: I think this is problem with my used date format I have used date format like this :date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($date)); as showing in above image date and month both with the single digit showing like 1/3/2017 instead of 01/03/2017 and this type of date not showing properly